# How do I get the correct date in Calendar to PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 version. I get the value of date calendar component.

The problem is that saved the day before the selected calendar days.

**Example**

Selected calendar days: 24/08/2013

Saved the day: 23/08/2013

I did this on the timezone setting in the web.xml.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This did not solve the problem.

I've set default timezone to attribute of the component.

```
private TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
<p:calendar value="#{controller.date}" timeZone="#{controller.timeZone}"/>
```

What can be done differently?

Basic components of my application:

JSF 2.2

Jetty 7.x Maven Plugin

MySql Server 5.6.13

JDK version 1.7

Comment: "Saved the day: 23/08/2013". How do you know that? Maybe when displaying the timezone is incorrect, and not when saving it?

Comment: I'm checking from the component value with System.out.println  before the database commit. Output: Sat Aug 24 00:00:00 EEST 2013

Comment: Okay, but I thought 24 is what you expected?

Comment: For example, returning value with new date Sun Aug 25 17:19:21 EEST 2013 Returning value with the component Sun Aug 25 00:00:00 EEST 2013 When I record with new date() is written to the database 25/08/2013 When I record with the value of the component is written to the database 24/08/2013 Problem is this.

Comment: Why are you concentrating your question so much on how you inputted and saved the date in DB, while the problem is clearly in outputting the date from DB? This makes your question only confusing. You should concentrate your question on outputting the date from DB.

Comment: I do not think the problem has to do with the db, because outputting the date from DB correct when recording with the new Date() Am I wrong?